# Writing to temporary directory does not work

Tags: objective-c, macos, temporary

I am trying to write a file to a temporary directory. I am doing it like this:

```
NSString *_location = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSString *_guid = [[NSCalendarDate calendarDate] descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%m%d%Y%H%M%S%F"];
_guid = [_guid stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
NSString *_tempFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", _location, _guid];
NSData *_temp_data = [imgRep representationUsingType: NSPNGFileType properties: nil];
[_temp_data writeToFile:_tempFilePath atomically: NO];
```

But it doesn't work for me. It doesn't create the file. What's the problem?

P.S. I have tried to create a directory with a unique name in NSTemporaryDirectory, and then write to a file there, but it didn't work either.

---

I noticed that it don't creates a file anywhere. Tried to set location to user's documents folder, but its not working.

Comment: Sorry, i've done mistake while rewriting a code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path for writing an image is incorrect:

```
NSString *_tempFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", _location,_guid];
```

OR

```
 NSString *_tempFilePath = [location stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"%@",guid];
```

Comment: It still doesn't creates a file. 

_tempFilePath looks like that:

`/var/folders/_n/fqxvr8rd543f3c9mvbd30_y40000gp/T/10252012155853582.png `, but the file is not created

Comment: No try again: `NSString *_tempFilePath = [location stringByAppendingPathComponent:guid];`

Comment: result is still the same. So I guess with location everything is OK, because if I remove `.png` and create directory, directory with that name is created successfully, but when I am trying to write a file with NSData `writeToFile` method it doesn't works

Answer (score 2):

If you write to a file inside potentially new directories, you have to first create the directory:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:_directoryPath
                           withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                            attributes:nil error:nil];

[_myData writeToFile:[_directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:_fileName]
          atomically:YES];
```

Comment: I'm not creating a directory, I'm just trying to write a file to the temporary directory that is already created by OS X.

Comment: @JuliusPetraška Didn't you say in the comment of Prince's answer that it works when you create the directory but not when you don't???

Comment: I meant that I can create a directory there but I can't create a file.

Comment: Make sure the base directory is inside the application documents folder. Any place outside this is not writable by your app.